# AWS Instance in LoadBalancer showing "OutOfService"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have created a stack from a cloud formation template and I can't get the load balancer to work with an instance (REST Server). In the availability zone the Healthy? status says "No (Availability Zone contains no healthy targets)".

I checked the security group and incoming ports are set to 8080 and outgoing are set to all.

I checked the instance and Tomcat is running. Why is the availability zone reporting no healthy targets?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with the health check ping target. You need to set the health check ping target to some file.

For example:

Use protocol `HTTP` on port `8080` and file `index.jsp`.

Then you can see in the health check option of ELB, ping target as `HTTP:8080/index.jsp`.

Here is the URL to AWS official [Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-healthchecks.html). For CloudFormation, have a look at this [syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb-health-check.html).